# Helm: ternary works, get/index fails. Why?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

The following command is messy, but works just fine:

```yaml
dict(
"resources" (ternary $args.resources (ternary $.Values.machines.micro (ternary $.Values.machines.small (ternary $.Values.machines.medium $.Values.machines.large (eq $args.machine "medium")) (eq $args.machine "small")) (eq $args.machine "micro")) (eq $args.machine nil))
)
```

The following 2 fail:

```yaml
"resources" (ternary $args.resources (index $.Values.machines $args.machine) (eq $args.machine nil))
"resources" (ternary $args.resources (get $.Values.machines $args.machine) (eq $args.machine nil))
```

With 2 respective errors:

```
# index
Error: template: tensor-etl-sol-chart/templates/template_deploys.yaml:65:40: executing "tensor-etl-sol-chart/templates/template_deploys.yaml" at <index $.Values.machines $args.machine>: error calling index: value is nil; should be of type string

# get
Error: template: tensor-etl-sol-chart/templates/template_deploys.yaml:65:67: executing "tensor-etl-sol-chart/templates/template_deploys.yaml" at <$args.machine>: wrong type for value; expected string; got interface {}
```

Why? And how to make it work?

Values.yaml:

```yaml
machines:
  micro:
    cpu: "250m"
    memory: "500Mi"
  small:
    cpu: "500m"
    memory: "1400Mi"
  medium:
    cpu: "1000m"
    memory: "3200Mi"
  large:
    cpu: "1500m"
    memory: "6900Mi"

...

  - name: 'inflate-bad-tmeta'
#    machine: small #<--- want to be able to uncomment this line, and should fallback to "resources" on the next lnie
    resources:
      cpu: '888m'
      memory: '888Mi'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As best I can tell, you'd want `|default` to make the `index` structure intact when they don't specify a `machine:` key at all, and then a separate `| default` for falling back to the inlined `resources:` block on bogus machine reference (as will be the case for both a missing `machine:` key as well as one that doesn't exist)

```yaml
# templates/debug.yaml
data:
  example: |
    {{ range .Values.things }}
    machine {{ .name }} is
    {{ (index 
      $.Values.machines
      (.machine | default "nope") 
      ) | default .resources }}
    {{ end }}
```

then, given

```yaml
machines:
  micro:
    cpu: "250m"
    memory: "500Mi"
  small:
    cpu: "500m"
    memory: "1400Mi"
  medium:
    cpu: "1000m"
    memory: "3200Mi"
  large:
    cpu: "1500m"
    memory: "6900Mi"

things:
  - name: 'inflate-bad-tmeta'
#    machine: small #<--- want to be able to uncomment this line, and should fallback to "resources" on the next lnie
    resources:
      cpu: '888m'
      memory: '888Mi'
```

it says

```
    machine inflate-bad-tmeta is
    map[cpu:888m memory:888Mi]
```

but given

```yaml
things:
  - name: 'inflate-bad-tmeta'
    machine: small
    resources:
      cpu: '888m'
      memory: '888Mi'
```

it says

```
    machine inflate-bad-tmeta is
    map[cpu:500m memory:1400Mi]
```

at your discretion whether you'd want to actually `fail` if *both* things are set, since it can cause the consumer to think their `resources:` win